# Symfony 3: headers set in WebTestCase are not present when retrieving request via Request::createFromGlobals()

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to write a functional test to validate a header sent along with a request. Using Symfony's WebTestCase i have:

```
$this->client->request(
            'POST',
            'my-endpoint',
            [],
            [],
            [
                'HTTP_My-custom-header' => 'some_value'
            ],
            $this->data);
```

Within a controller, i can see the headers as expected form the $request argument passed in to an action method.

However, the code i am testing is not a controller, and retrieves the current request (and therefore headers) via Request::createFromGlobals(). From this context, the header is missing.

Why is the header missing?

thanks

Comment: I suppose you could try adding it to $_SERVER but assuming your code is part of a symfony app then it should be pulling the request from the request stack instead of making a new one.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/request.html

Comment: Adding it to $_SERVER didn't work unfortunately. I think you are correct about injecting the request stack instead, but in this case i'm working with contributed code so i can't change the way it pulls information from the request (its not a Symfony bundle but does rely on Symfony components). It seems like Request::createFromGlobals() cannot see information set by WebTestCase, which is strange given they are both Symfony components

Comment: Not strange at all.  WebTestCase is basically a wrapper around phpunit.  It is designed specifically for Symfony applications.  Bit surprised that $_SERVER did not work.  Make sure you use all caps with HTTP_ prefix.

Comment: I've just noticed that not only are the headers missing when using WebTestCase, but also the POST data is missing. I'm new to automated testing and its possible i have fundamentally misunderstood how WebTestCase works.. i thought it was supposed to mimic an HTTP client (like Guzzle), but clearly it has limitations which are not immediately obvious

Comment: I find web test cases to be a bit fragile and not much help.  Prefer unit test cases.  However your basic problem is that you are trying to use a symfony test runner on non-symfony code.  Might want to look elsewhere.